# Does the Jaculi need to spring at least 10 feet to do the extra 2d6 damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The Jaculi has a special action, **spring**:

> **Spring**. The jaculi springs up to 30 feet in a straight line and makes a bite attack against a target within its reach. This attack has advantage if the jaculi springs at least 10 feet. If the attack hits, the bite deals an extra 7 (2d6) piercing damage.

Does the Jaculi need to springs at least 10 feet to deal the extra damage? Or can it do a tiny spring (<= 1 feet) and do the full damage?

If the spring can be arbitrary small, it won't trigger opportunity attacks. So Spring becomes strictly better than a normal **Bite**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The attack only needs to hit to deal extra damage

> **If the attack hits**, the bite deals an extra 7 (2d6) piercing damage.

However if you spring at least 10 feet then the jaculi will have advantage:

> This attack has advantage **if the jaculi springs at least 10 feet**

Answer (score 4):

### No

Each sentence in the quote stands on its own. If it springs 10 feet or more it gets advantage. If it springs any distance it gets the extra damage.